# Email causing mysqli query to fail

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to run a simple query which inserts some data into a user table, but email (@ sign to be more specific) is causing the query to fail. Here's the code:

```
$query = "insert into user (username, password, email) value (?,?,?)";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
  $this->email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($this->email);
  $stmt->bind_param('sss', $this->screenName, $this->password, $this->email);
  $stmt->execute();
  if ($mysqli->affected_rows != -1) {
    $this->uid = $stmt->insert_id;
    $response = array("status" => "success");
  } else {
    $response = array("error" => "db error while inserting");   //db error
  }
} else {
  $response = array("error" => "db error");   //db error
}
```

It just prints db error while inserting, ideally it should return me "success"
NOTE: This is just a code snippet. Assume db connections are all working fine.

Comment: Can you show us the error message plz ?

Comment: Have you tried make a var_dump of the vars and the query before launching it?

Comment: What's the *actual* error from the database?  Anything from `mysqli_error()` or in the logs?  The string "db error" that you made up doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Try to catch the DB error to see what went wrong

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this "$mysqli->affected_rows != -1"?

Comment: @Jay Bhatt : yes agreed, that can go away & I can simply use $stmt->insert_id

Comment: SOLVED : problem was in the query ... it's insert into <table name> () values () ... & I wrote "value" ... but surprisingly that also worked in mySql :-/ ... i tried the query before manually & it worked

Comment: @ OP You really should always inspect the PDOStatement::errorInfo() values when running into this kind of wall. Would have solved your problem in seconds. PDOStatement::errorInfo() will return an array of error code and message information.